# EditText widget in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-4.2-jelly-bean

While developing for Android version 4.0 and later, I found that the EditText widget has been modified and the upper half of the textbox has disappeared. Well, that is the way later versions of Android OS represents EditText widget.

My question is, is there any way to get those *Gingerbread* style EditText in Android 4.0 and later versions? If yes then how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply background to `EditText` using xml or image by setting `android:background` tag in xml

Answer (score 0):

i think u r using holo theme for your app..otherwise it will come four side edittext only..in holo theme only no upper half..check it in manifest file..